# JPA multiple inheritence

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, model, multiple-inheritance

I've this kind of **data model:**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Operaton {
    @Id
    private int id;
  
}

@Entity
public class Payment extends Operaton {

}
@Entity
public class Transfer extends Operaton /*, Operation1*/ {

}

@Entity
public class Payout extends Operaton1 {
}

@Repository
public interface OperationRepo extends JpaRepository<Operation, Integer>{

    Page<Operation> findAll(Pageable pageable);// can obtain page of Payments and Transfers sorted by date

}

public interface OperationRepo1 extends JpaRepository<Operation1, Integer>{

    Page<Operation1> findAll(Pageable pageable);// can't obtain page of Transfers and Payouts sorted by date for other view

}
```

This works well when I need united pagination for one kind of balance report, where Payment + and Transfer -.
However now I need to show pages where Transfer recipient is getting balance pages where Transfer + and Payout as -.
Obviously I can't just extend Payout as Operation this way, because I don't need 3-class mutual repository which will provide me pagination. I need 2 repos for 3 tables. Mapping is not a problem, the fields in superclass contains all I need in both cases. But without multiple inheritance I didn't found a good elegant solution so far, appreciate any help. I use Spring Boot 3.1.2

Update:

If there was some way to define second Entity to Transfer table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transfer")
public class TransferSecond extends Operation1
```

It would solve a problem and even will not create any if it can be done in a read-only way.
Currently causes org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, just don't use inheritance. Inheritance doesn't match the model of a relational database and will always be clumsy. Instead, just define a type enum for your operation, and use a single table. Some database columns will only apply to specific types, which is really not a problem except that it may limit some database-level validation somewhat.

If you only need a certain kind of operation, it's easy to filter on that. If you need all, you have everything together and paging works easily.

If you insist on using the `@Inheritance` annotation then you probably also get this to work with the `SINGLE_TABLE` variant, which is basically this but then with a little more magic by the JPA implementation.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about this reasonable alternative while modeling and I just dont like when table is like slice of cheese full of nulls. It will work, but data migration is not a pleasant thing to do.

Comment: @LudovDmitrii yeah it's not ideal either, but relational databases simply weren't built with inheritance in mind and if you want to depend on your database for smart querying, paging and sorting then I think this is the way. If you don't need pagination so much or the total amount of data is always pretty small, you can use multiple tables. But it does limit your total I/O quite a bit. Querying multiple tables for just a simple result is not ideal either.

Comment: To convince the customer that pagination is not needed here; this is the second solution that I am considering along with the first; it’s nice to understand that these thoughts are common sense. No one will actually leaf through these pages, which is usually what happens. For a general report, I can finally generate a CSV.

Comment: However, I came up with the idea of making 2 entities on the same table with transfers (read-only), but hibernate does not allow this yet.